# Deploy Sencha 4.2.1 with MVC 4 Web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, extjs, deployment

I am creating a MVC4 web application and i am using sencha 4.2.1 library which i downloaded from sencha website. Library size is 300+ MB so i can not deploy this package to IIS. So please let me know how can i deploy website along with sencha to IIS.

Thanks,
Nishant

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all of those files in your project.
This is the File Structure as described in the ExtJS Sencha tutorials.

[image: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/guides/application_architecture/folderStructure.png]

For more details visit : 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#/guide/application_architecture

Answer (score 0):

You should use Sencha CMD to build a minified single javascript file for deployment purposes.

http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/3.1.2/#!/guide/command